# WebClient won't work on one website

Tags: c#, winforms, http, webclient

I am trying to download the html code of a website(yellowpages) to a string in my C# winforms application.

I keep getting the same error from one website. 
All the other websites work, I have tried the generic ones like: http://www.google.co.za and it works but when I try to use http://www.yellowpages.co.za it throws out:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error.*

I have no idea why only this one website is throwing out this error.

**Please find my code below**

```
private string getPage()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadString("http://www.yellowpages.co.za/");               
    }
}
```

Comment: At a rough guess, they're doing some sort of validation to avoid people using data beyond their terms of use. You can probably see this yourself if you use a HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)

Comment: Isn't there a way around this? If I can view and download the page source in Chrome why can't i do so in C#?

Comment: @user3815511: Chrome is sending a lot more metadata like the browser type, supported compression mechanisms, the source IP address of the request. This is some ways gives the web servers more assurance that the request is coming from a browser and not a scraper. The code above is just to get that page with nothing about the initiating client; e.g. you aren't downloading CSS or images - you could be scraping the material off the site. Some websites use firewalls to block requests like this; it is a common way to implement a DoS attack.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand. So is there no way what so ever that I can work around this?

Comment: If you use Fiddler, as suggested by @RowlandShaw, it will show you what headers are in place. Add these to the `client.Headers` collection before the request and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `user-agent` header fixes this.

```
private string getPage()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "foo");
            return client.DownloadString("http://www.yellowpages.co.za/");               
    }
}
```

That said, I would put a valid value for `user-agent` and not a placeholder like `foo`. See [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) for details on user-agent.